# Revert Back PowerShell after "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force"

Tags: powershell

Since i need to update `npm` manually using `npm-windows-upgrade`,

i put

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

setting into my PowerShell.

Now i already finished updating `npm`, so i need to return the PowerShell setting to previous state, i.e. rollback the `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force`, how to do that?

Comment: how, npm upgrade is related to PowerShell execution policy ?

Comment: @PRASOONKARUNANV: The OP is using the [`npm-windows-upgrade`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade) npm package, which runs a PowerShell script.

Comment: As an aside: you don't need a package just to upgrade `npm` itself; e.g., run `npm install npm@latest -g` to upgrade to the latest version. As for the package: if it invoked `powershell.exe` with `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`, there would be no need to (poorly) instruct users to fiddle with the execution policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the current execution policy via `get-executionpolicy`
So you might save that state in a variable and use it later on to reset the state.

```
$ep = get-executionpolicy
set-executionpolicy $ep
```

Comment: If you already forgot the state of user scope execution policy, you can just set it to "Restricted" and have someone who would need it differnt set it for himself. Since you seem to be using scripts pretty often, you'd better set it to "RemoteSigned" instead.

Comment: Many users don't know how to do this. You're right, but if you have a script for an admin to run, and he doesn't know powershell, which is common, he won't even know execution policy is a thing.